# Render JSON associations with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have defined serializers for all my models and the following call executes successfully:

```
render json: @setup, include: ["items.media_contents"]
```

I now want to include another model inside the rendered JSON, but when I do the following I receive an `undefined method: items.media_contents` error. How can I include more models?

```
render json: { display: @display, setup: @setup.to_json(include: ["items.media_contents"]) }
```